# Fedora - после обновления не запускается systemd-resolved

Tags: linux, dns, fedora

На следующий день после очередного обновления Fedora запускаю комп и обнаруживаю, что иНет исчез. Локалка работает, пинги по явному IP ходят куда угодно. А вот использование FQDN не прокатывает - система говорит, что сервер не найден. Не работает почтовый клиент, скайп, интернет браузер, системное обновление из репозитараиев - ничего!

И только один Telegram работает как ни в чём не бывало.

Пошёл на другой комп - искать в интернете ответ. Ответ нашёлся довольно быстро:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/fedora-33-how-to-persist-dns-settings-via-etc-resolv-conf

Подправил одну строчку в указанном файле, перестартовал сервис и всё заработало. Я уже собирался праздновать победу, но тут выяснилось, что после перезагрузки, ситуация вернулась - DNS не рабоьтает. Хотя содержимое файла не изменилось:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001
# Google:     8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112 2620:fe::fe 2620:fe::9
DNS=192.168.0.1
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=resolve
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

Единственная строчка, которую я дописал осталась. Но почему-то не воспринялась. Я перестартовал сервис:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

и всё опять заработало.

Но остались сомнения... Мне что - теперь каждый раз так делать ?!

Comment: дык, вроде ты же уже гвоздями прибил dns на указанный адрес (подразумевая, что ты не пользуешься NM'ом)... дальше надо только вспомнить об этом при переезда хоста в новую сеть... я бы больше беспокоился, почему корректный dns не получается по dhtp...

Comment: @Fat-Zer -"почему корректный dns не получается по dhcp". - Это действительно странно... Я подозреваю, что DHCP вообще не отрабатывает, а IP и маску ОС настраивает просто по последним значениям. Но на роутере сервер DHCP работает, на хосте клиент тоже,  вроде бы, запускается...